Looking for the name of a Bollywood film starring Rakhee
I am trying to recall the name of a Bollywood film from the 70s or 80s which had Rakhee Gulzar in a pivotal role. (I am not certain if she was the protagonist but she featured prominently.) It belonged to the drama genre if I recall correctly, possibly featuring a plot involving marital infidelity but I could be wrong about that part.
The most vivid memory I have is of a scene where she is caressing a flower and trying to recall its English name. She utters the dialogue 'Calendula. धत, वो तो गेंदे का फ़ूल है.' (English translation: Calendula. Darn it, that's the name of the marigold flower.) This dialogue is uttered several times by Rakhee's character and finally at the end of the movie, she is able to recall the correct name.
I do not remember much more from the movie and even though this seems very vague I'm hoping someone has seen this movie and remembers the name.

Do you mean Rakhee Gulzar ?

@Rahul: Yes, Rakhee Gulzar. Sorry, I was going to link to her Wiki page, forgot to do it, adding it in now.

Any other co-stars or scenes you remember ? That would be helpful.

@Rahul: No, sorry. This is all I am able to remember. I know it's too vague. I tried my own internet sleuthing and turned up blank. I'm still hopeful MoviesSE can help.

One way to find out will be to go through stories of all the movies from Rakhee Gulzar's Filmography. ☺☻

@Rahul I have already tried that but several movies in that list (consider this example) have very brief synopses which will very likely omit out the description of the one repeating scene I remember, which might be insignificant for plot progression. For all I know, the example could very well be the movie I am looking for, but at this point, the only way to figure it out myself would be to watch most of these movies. Which is why I turned to SE for help.

The movie you are talking about is Paroma (Parama, A 40-year-old married woman falls in love with a young man) English title "The Ultimate Woman" released in 1984 in Hindi and Bengali language which was directed by Aparna Sen, starring Rakhee Gulzar, Aparna Sen and Mukul Sharma. And yes you are absolutely correct on that part which involves marital infidelity where women are held to higher standard of morality. Her husband had affairs himself but still could not tolerate his wife having an affair. I am also attaching the link of youtube video where she speaks about the flower which is in Bengali language and i love the background music. Hope you enjoy.

Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.
